# "All users at/in/of LocationX": What should it be?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm creating a software and need help for naming user groups in a generic way. Each name includes a user role and a location description.

Examples of user roles:

- Administrator
- Author
- Reviewer

Examples of location names:

- Chicago, IL
- Sidney Navel Base
- Albacerky Chemical Plant
- Plant no. 6

Now, which of the following examples do you think works best?

Example 1

- All [LOCATION] users
- All [LOCATION] administrators
- All [LOCATION] authors

Example 2

- All users of [LOCATION]
- All administrators of [LOCATION]
- All authors of [LOCATION]

Example 3

- All users in [LOCATION]
- All administrators in [LOCATION]
- All authors in [LOCATION]

Example 4

- All users at [LOCATION]
- All administrators at [LOCATION]
- All authors at [LOCATION]

Example 5

- All users at the [LOCATION] site
- All administrators at the [LOCATION] site
- All authors at the [LOCATION] site

Example 6

- All users of the [LOCATION] site
- All administrators of the [LOCATION] site
- All authors of the [LOCATION] site

Example 7

- All users located at [LOCATION]
- All administrators located at [LOCATION]
- All authors located at [LOCATION]

I think the right choice is between examples 2, 3 and 4, but I'm unsure and can't explain why.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the naming of software components and aspects is expressly out of bounds per the FAQ. (Also see [this Meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1088/2303)).

Comment: I would say that examples 1 and 6 work best because they include all users/admin/authors, both those working on site and those working remotely.  Compare this to examples 3, 4, 5 and 7 which appear to exclude workers accessing the site remotely.  Examples 2 also works if you add the determiner *the* to Sidney and Albecerky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Example 7 for its specificity referring to a given place as opposed to *In* which could also be taken to mean a position.  *Of* could be taken to mean from or to mean the subjective case, so I would rule that out as ambiguous.  That said, *At* is the best choice but one of those tricky words that could also have a character meaning in that context (@) so I don't know if that takes you into the weeds, so to speak.

Comment: I have to say that "at" is probably my best option since "in" and "of" don't exactly satisfy me in all cases. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Imgoing with 2. Just sounds right. He said he wants to name user groups in a generic way, or generically, right?